# closest string match in Elixir or Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to compare 2 strings which are basically addresses.

I was trying to use `jaro_distance`

```
iex(1)> String.jaro_distance("4420 West Main Street", "EUTECTIC CORPORATION QA testing1")
0.49107142857142855
```

but there is no similarity between the 2 strings.

I also tried PSQL `SIMILAR TO` as well. in this way

```
  def find_match(seeker_company_id, string, type) do
    search = "%(" <> string <> ")%"
    base_query =
      from op in OpenCorporates,
        where: op.seeker_company_id == ^seeker_company_id

    base_query
    |> type_query(type, search)
    |> Repo.aggregate(:count)
  end

  defp type_query(query, :name, value) do
    from op in query,
      where: fragment("? SIMILAR TO ?", op.name, ^value)
  end

  defp type_query(query, :address, value) do
    from op in query,
      where: fragment("? SIMILAR TO ?", op.registered_address, ^value)
  end
```

but if the search string and actual strings are like this

Search string: '`29 SANTA CRUZ COURT PITTSBURG CA 662354553`' and actual address string: '`29 SANTA CRUZ COURT PITTSBURG CA 94565`'

it fails as well. but it should not fail here because most of the string matches.

so what could be a solution here to this, is there a way to calculate the percentage of the match? in the above case, we can say that it is 80% match.

any guidance will be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see about what you get with [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance calculation or [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). I would also point out that the way a Jaro distance is calculated (at least according to Wikipedia) ["The score is normalized such that 0 means an exact match and 1 means there is no similarity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance)--well a score of .49 does seem to indicate a significant difference.